# jQuery - Passing variable to PHP

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am trying to pass a jQuery variable to PHP using AJAX but it does not seem to be passing. For testing purposes I have the following:

JQUERY:

```
            var runin_pickup = 1200;

            // Send to our checkRuninTariff function
            checkRuninTariff(runin_pickup);
```

`

```
function checkRuninTariff(runin_pickup) {

$.ajax({

         // Request sent from control panel, so send to cp.request.php (which is the handler)
        url: 'scripts/php/bootstrp/all.request.php',
        type: 'POST',

        // Build data array - look at the '$_REQUEST' parameters in the 'insert' function
        data: 'fnme=runIn&field_runin_p='+runin_pickup,
        dataType: 'text',
        timeout: 20000,
        error: function(){
                alert("There was a problem...")
        },
        success: function(){
                alert(runin_pickup+' passed successfully')
        }
    });

}
```

This gets passed to all.request.php:

```
<?php

include('../../../deployment.php');
require_once('controllers/xml.controller.php');
require_once('controllers/tariff.fare.controller.php');
require_once('controllers/datagrid.controller.php');
require_once('controllers/get.bookings.php');


// Switch to determine method to call
switch ($_REQUEST['fnme']) {

case 'runIn':
header('Content-type: text/html');
echo TariffFareController::getFare($_REQUEST['field_runin_p']);
break;

case 'g_fare':

header('Content-type: text/html');

echo TariffFareController::fareRequestHandler($_REQUEST['v_sys'],$_REQUEST['j_dis'],$_REQUEST['pc_arr'],
    $_REQUEST['leg_arr'],$_REQUEST['return_j'],$_REQUEST['j_date'],$_REQUEST['j_time'],
    $_REQUEST['r_date'],$_REQUEST['r_time'],$_REQUEST['wait_return_j']);

break;
}
```

And finally to the tariff.fare.controller.php:

```
public static function getFare($int_terminate,$fieldPickup) {

        if($fieldPickup > 1100) {

            $fare = 222.00;
        }
        else {
        $fare = 111.00;
        }

}
```

In the firebug console I can see that `field_runin_p = 1200`

However, if I do a var_dump($fieldPickup); this is NULL when it should be `1200`. Any ideas why this is not working?

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Your function requires two arguments:

`getFare($int_terminate, $fieldPickup)`

Your code however, passes only one (and it doesn't match the var you are expecting to be in):

`echo TariffFareController::getFare($_REQUEST['field_runin_p']);`

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to send html from your PHP - `header('Content-type: text/html');` but you are telling your javascript to expect plaintext - `dataType: 'text',`

Use `header('Content-type: text/plain');` instead.

The other posters point out other problems with your script.

I'd also advise against using `$_REQUEST` as your data could be coming from GET or POST parameters, and you wouldn't know which.